# Is there a definition of Riemann integration in $\mathbb{R^n}$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral

I know that Riemann integration is well-defined for a function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.

I would like to ask whether there is a definition of Riemann integration for a function $f: \mathbb{R^n} \to \mathbb{R}$ ? If there is not, are there technical reasons to prevent such a definition ?

The reason for the question is to understand more about the motivation to construct the Lebesgue integration.

Thanks for your explanation!

Comment: Definitely. It's covered in a bunch of real analysis textbooks such as Calculus on Manifolds by Spivak.

Comment: There are no technical reasons that prevent is definition (as the answer explains). In a pure math context, there are sometimes pedagogical reasons it is avoided - the machinery of partitions is not really any easier to work with than the machinery of simple functions; many theorems are not much easier to prove; and many results you might want to have don't hold, for reasons that are specific to the Riemann integral. It's nevertheless very helpful to have the Riemann "picture" in mind when studying Lebesgue integration, and to (eventually) see that for nice functions the concepts coincide.

Comment: Of course there is. This is what mathematicians in the late 1800's were working overtime on. But it's awkward and mired in technicalities when $n>1.$ In higher dimensions the Lebesgue integral saves us from this tedium.

Answer (score 3):

There is such a notion, which is used often in multivariable calculus before one introduces the Lebesgue integral. The motivation is the same - we want the volume under the graph of $f: \mathbb R^n \longrightarrow \mathbb R$. The approach of summing the area of rectangles with Riemann sums generalizes to summing the volume of higher dimensional rectangles.

Formally, a single variable Riemann sum of a bounded function $f: [a, b] \longrightarrow \mathbb R$ is a sum of the form $\sum_{i=0}^n f(t_i^*) (t_{i + 1} - t_i)$ where $a = t_0 < \dots < \ t_n = b$ is a partition of $[a, b]$ and $t_i^* \in [t_i, t_{i+1}]$. That is, we sample $f$ on these subintervals and sum the corresponding rectangle's areas. We say that $f$ is Riemann integrable if the limit of these expressions as the mesh size $\delta = \sup (t_{i+1} - t_i)$ goes to $0$. This limit is called the Riemann integral of $f$ and is denoted $\int_a^b f(x) dx$.

With this review aside, we can see a clear path to generalizing this to multivariable calculus. Take a rectanglesm $R = [a_1, b_1] \times \dots \times [a_n, b_n]$ and let $f: R \longrightarrow \mathbb R$ be bounded. Previously, we took smaller and smaller partitions of our interval $[a, b]$ into subintervals. Here, we'll partition our rectangle $R$ into subrectangles. Specifically, we consider partitions $R = \bigcup R_i$ where $R_i$ is a product of subintervals of $[a_i, b_i]$. We consider only "almost disjoint" unions $R_i$, meaning that if $i \neq j$ then $R_i$ and $R_j$ can intersect only on their boundaries. You can picture a partition of, say, a rectangle in $\mathbb R^2$ by drawing finitely many lines parallel to the axes which start from one edge and go to the parallel edge. The resulting "brick wall" is a partition. For higher dimensions, you do this with hyperplanes instead of lines.

Now, given such a partition, a Riemann sum for this partition is a sum of the form $\sum_i f(R_i^*) m(R_i)$ where $R_i^* \in R_i$ and $m(R_i)$ is the volume of the rectangle $R_i$, which is defined as the product of its side lengths. This is just like the single variable case - we sample $f$ along a partition and approximate the volume under its graph by these Riemann sums.

To finally define an integral, we need a limit of these sums. We define the diamter of a rectangle to be the largest distance between any two points in the rectangle (which is realized as the long diagonal). The mesh size of a partition $\bigcup R_i$ is the largest diameter of the $R_i$. Then we say $f$ is Riemann integrable if the limit of these Riemann sums as the mesh size goes to $0$ exists, and this limit is called the Riemann integral of $f$ and is denoted $\int_R f(x_1, \dots, x_n) dx_1 \dots dx_n$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It helps. Could you please suggest me an article or a book that define/discuss the definition of Riemann integral in $\mathbb{R^n}$ please ? I would like to have a rigorous view of this definition. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: To add more clarity to my previous comment, I mean I see the Riemann integration is rigorously defined using the Upper Riemann integration and Lower Riemann integration. I appreciate your definition as taking the limit $\delta_{i} \to 0$ but would like a more rigorous kind of "set-theoretic" definition.

Comment: You can formalize this by saying $\forall \varepsilon > 0$, $\exists \delta > 0$ st $|x - \sum f(R_i*) m(R_i)|< \varepsilon$ for any partition $\bigcup R_i$ with mesh $< \delta$. $x$ is then the integral of $f$. You could also consider the lower and upper sums (often called Darboux sums). These bound the Riemann sums I write down so the lower and upper sums definition is the same as mine. [This](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/m125b/ch1.pdf) discusses this equivalence for the single variable case. See Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds for the Darboux treatment in the multivariable case.